# s3 set file real name on upload in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i use Laravel 6.x , My question is - how can I set the real file name(which is not the uuid), so when I download the key from S3 later - the file that will be downloaded will be named as the real file name?

I've read about Content-Disposition header but I think this is only in download request and I want to do this on upload request
This my code :

```
 $music = request()->file('music');
$mu_name = $music->getOriginalClientName();
Storage::disk('s3')->put('musics', $mu_name);
```

Comment: And this code is not working?

Comment: No, and i want thé url of file db